# splitting multiple lists in 1 big list into seperate lists

Tags: python, python-3.9

I have the following list:

```
order = [['S', ['PINEAPPLE']], ['M', ['PINEAPPLE']], ['L', ['PINEAPPLE']]]
```

I want to split this list into seperate lists so that it will look like this

```
order1 = ['S', ['PINEAPPLE']]

order2 = ['M', ['PINEAPPLE']]

order3 = ['L', ['PINEAPPLE']]
```

I would also like to know if its possible to make "order 1-3" into tuples instead of lists

I tried:

```
orders = order_str.split(",")
```

but that only works for strings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 1):

You can just unpack to those variable names from the list.

```
order = [['S', ['PINEAPPLE']], ['M', ['PINEAPPLE']], ['L', ['PINEAPPLE']]]
order1, order2, order3 = order

print(order2)
```

output

```
['M', ['PINEAPPLE']]
```

To return as tuples use;

```
order1, order2, order3 = map(tuple, order)
```

Comment: thank you, the only problem that I'll have with this is that the number of lists inside "order" can change and thus the number of new lists I need will change. For example I might need to create more lists called order and order 5.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of situation collections like `list` and `dict` are made for.

Comment: In the [`collections` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html), there's also `deque` which is good for building *first in first out* queues.  You can append to the end and pop off the front as required, and the left pop is much more efficient in a `deque` than a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looping through the list and naming a variable ordern; n being a number.

```
order = [['S', ['PINEAPPLE']], ['M', ['PINEAPPLE']], ['L', ['PINEAPPLE']]]
for i in range(len(order)):
    locals()['order'+str(i+1)] = order[i]
print(order1)
print(order2)
print(order3)
```

`locals()[string]` is used to convert string into a variable name so you can have as many order variables as you need. 
You can then use the `tuple(list)` function to get a tuple from whatever list you want.
I don't understand why you want to seperate them but hope it helps